# Check Which Path exists and IF...Test-path PS

Tags: powershell, cluster-computing, powershell-2.0, system-administration

**Actual File Configuration:**
clustername=GLA-CLU2

fswmain=\DC01\SQL-FSW1

fswdr=\DC01\SQL-FSW2

**My actual script:**

```html
### BEGIN OF Passing as Variables, the configuration values separated with '=' and Retrieved from the indicated TXT file:
Get-Content '.\FSW_pathConf.txt' | Foreach-Object {
   $Vconfvalue = $_.Split('=')
   New-Variable -Name $Vconfvalue[0] -Value $Vconfvalue[1] }
### END OF Passing values as Variables
### Testing Each Path defined into configuration file
$currentfsw = Get-clusterresource -cluster $clustername | where-object {$_.ResourceType -like "File Share Witness"} | get-clusterparameter -Name "sharepath" | Select Value
Write-Host "`r"
Write-Host "the current file share witness configuration On Cluster: '$($Clustername)' is: '$($currentfsw)' " 

if($currentfsw -is "$fswmain") {Test-Path -Path "$fswmain" -IsValid}

else{Set-ClusterQuorum -Cluster $Clustername -NodeAndFileShareMajority "$fswdr"}


if($currentfsw -is "$fswdr") { Test-Path -Path "$fswdr" -IsValid}

else{Set-ClusterQuorum -Cluster $Clustername -NodeAndFileShareMajority "$fswmain" }
```

**What I would like to do whcih im struggling with:**

if $fswmain is valid then return "OK,current fsw is working" and stop this script here

If not $currentfsw is no valid then run the command below to swith to $fswdr

Then, only if $currentfsw is not equal to $fswmain

if $fswdr is valid then return "OK,current fsw is working" and stop this script here

If not run the command below to switch to $fswmain

Any could bring some help here ? I am quite new with powershell and sysadmin

Thank you.

Comment: `$NewFswPath = if(Test-Path $path1) { $path1 }else{ $path2 }`?

Comment: I'll try that...and get back to you.Thanks

Comment: I managed to make work the whole script, thanks for your help !

Comment: Hi, 
there is a defect into the script I wrote ( see below) IF "$path1" is accessible I would like to return an OK and stop the script, cause actually whatever the status he will continue to set a new qourum file share witness...

Thank a lot for your help.

Comment: Please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65145606/edit), code in comments are not easily readable :)